# How can I write a typedef for a function pointer to accept different types of arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, typedef, stdmap

Currently I have a function pointer to perform some actions based on the user inputs, like this:

```
typedef int(A::*FUNCPTR)(); 
std::map<const std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map;
```

```
func_map["sum"]  = &A::cmd_sum;
func_map["print"]  = &A::cmd_print;
```

So the function declaration in class A is like this:

```
int cmd_sum();
int cmd_print();
```

And then based on the user input, one of the two functions is performed. Both of them returns an int.

Now I am trying to extend it, in a way that my function `cmd_sum` receives two `int` values as argument but my function `cmd_print` keeps receiving nothing, since I am gonna print `Hello world`. How can I do this?

What I mean:

```
typedef int(A::*FUNCPTR)(//Do something here); 
std::map<const std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map;
```

```
func_map["sum"]  = &A::cmd_sum;
func_map["print"]  = &A::cmd_print;
```

In a way that I can have this in the end:

```
int cmd_sum(int a, int b);
int cmd_print();
```

Comment: how are you going to call the functions?  `func_map["sum"]( .... ?!?...)` ? you need to know if you should pass nothing or an `int`

Comment: Stary by thinking how you are going to call them. This will give you a hint about how these should be declared. You can treat arbitrary user input as a (dynamic) array of parameters. And then your functions can just accept array/vector. That is one way to deal with it.

Comment: in other words, whats the purpose of the map? When you use a key to look up a function, where is the key coming from?

Comment: The user inserts a string and the map is useful to convert this user command in an action. The main problem is in the typedef I think because here `typedef int(dac_sim::dac_ifs::dac_sim_cmd_if::*FUNCPTR)(void);`

Comment: you need the string and you need to know how many parameters to pass, at compile time. suppose you get a string from user, then you cannot call `func_map[user_string]( 1,2)`, because the function either takes 0 or 2 integers, not both, and the typedef won't help. The easiest would be to always use a vector of integers, that can have different size at runtime

Comment: i think it would really help if you show an example of usage, to clarify the question and for you to understand the problem

Comment: The point of a `typedef` or `using` declaration is just to have a convenient alias for a type. It's not "to accept different types".

Comment: freakish has the right idea.  Note that creation of an adaptor from the script-like dynamic array of parameters to an ordinary function accepting separate parameters can be automated using a variable template.  Said adaptor would check the number of actual arguments against the length of the type parameter pack, coerce each argument to the correct type, and finally call the ordinary function.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not easily possible. You cannot store functions of different type in the same map. Not directly. You can apply type erasure. Erasing the type is relatively simple, but eventually you do need to know if the function takes 0 or 2 integers, otherwise you cannot call it.

To be clear: A typedef does not help. A typedef is merely an alias for a type. If it cannot be done without the alias, it cannot be done with the alias. There is no function type you can use for the map, that would match `cmd_sum` and `cmd_add`. There is no type that you could give a name to.

The simple solution, as suggested in a comment, is to change the signature to always take a `vector`:

```
int cmd_sum(std::vector<int> x);
int cmd_print(std::vector<int> x);
```

Whether this or a more compilcated solution is viable depends on details.

For type erasure there are several options, not necessarily the best, but perhaps among the most simple is to have a common base class:

```
 struct abstract_command {
     virtual ~abstract_command() {}
 };
```

And then use a `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<abstract_command>>`. However, this is only the "erasing" part of type erasure. Before you can call the function you will need to restore the type (eg a call with arguments `T...` could trigger a dynamic cast to `command<T...>` with appropriate `operator()`).

Answer (score 0):

A pointer-to-member-function can safely be casted to another type of pointer-to-member-function and then casted back to the original type.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> 10. A pointer to member function can be converted to pointer to a different member function of a different type. Conversion back to the original type yields the original value, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be used safely.

So, you *could* do something like the following (I don't *advise* doing this, but it is *legal* to do this):

```
class A {
public:
    int cmd_sum(int a, int b);
    int cmd_print();
};

...

typedef void(A::*FUNCPTR)(); 
std::map<std::string, FUNCPTR> func_map;

func_map["sum"]   = reinterpret_cast<FUNCPTR>(&A::cmd_sum);
func_map["print"] = reinterpret_cast<FUNCPTR>(&A::cmd_print);

...

typedef int(A::*SUMFUNCPTR)(int,int);
SUMFUNCPTR sum = reinterpret_cast<SUMFUNCPTR>(func_map["sum"]);
(someAObj->*sum)(123, 456);

...

typedef int(A::*PRINTFUNCPTR)();
PRINTFUNCPTR print = reinterpret_cast<PRINTFUNCPTR>(func_map["print"]);
(someAObj->*print)();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/57ooO4)